# Removing scrollbars from Content Editor/Page Viewer Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, moss, web-parts, cewp

I am trying to display an HTML page inside another SharePoint webpart page.

I used the Out-of-the-box page viewer webpart, but the page viewer webpart displays a disabled scrollbar inside it.

I also tried using a content editor webpart with an IFRAME tag in it, but still it didnt't work.

This is the code i used in the content editor webpart.

```
<iframe name="Iframe" src="URL1" scrolling="no"
    FRAMEBORDER="0" style="width:100%; border:0;  height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"width:100%;height:100%" may be the culprit. make size of the iframe larger than the frame window. Also try using scrolling="no"

Answer (score 3):

Use this on your stylesheet:

```
#s4-workspace {

   overflow-y: hidden !important;

   overflow-x: hidden !important;

}
```

Comment: In my case I had to target a specific ID, #WebPartWPQ2, for a right-side CEWP showing scrollbars, but your CSS did the job. Thanks.

Comment: This is _tremendous_. lovely solution to an annoying "problem".

Answer (score 1):

I get the best results with the web capture web part instead of the page viewer web part.

Make sure your content doesn't have defined sizes (so it flows in the smaller frame) and then tweak the web capture part sizes until the scroll bars disappear.

Cheers,
Reeves